# Python Regex Matching - Splitting on punctuation but ignoring certain words

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following sentence,

> Hi, my name is Dr. Who. I'm in love with fish-fingers and custard !!

I'm trying to capture the punctuation (except the apostrophe and hyphen) using regular expressions, but I also want to ignore certain words. For example, I'm ignoring Dr., and so I don't want to capture the . in the word Dr.

Ideally, the regex should capture the text in between the parentheses:

> Hi(, )my( )name( )is( )Dr.( )Who(. )I'm( )in( )love( )with( )fish-fingers( )and( )custard( !!)

Note that I have a Python list that contains words like "Dr." that I want to ignore. I'm also using string.punctuation to get a list of punctuation characters to use in the regex. I've tried using negative lookahead but it was still catching the "." in Dr. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the position of the words relevant? Or is it just the words in the list you want to ignore. It might be easier to first remove the words you want to ignore first. Can you give a full example?

Comment: This is difficult to do with a regular expression. You want a regexp that matches punctuation, but with a negative lookbehind to ignore certain words. But negative lookbehinds have to be fixed length, and your words to ignore might not all be the same length.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a NLP library for this?

Comment: I did try ntlk and spacey but it isn't entirely what I want.

Comment: Do you mean, "in between the pairs of parenthesis?" Like, do you want to capture `['Hi', 'my' ...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can throw away at first all your stop words (like "Dr.") and then all letters (and digits).

```
import re

text = "Hi, my name is Dr. Who. I'm in love with fish-fingers and custard !!"
tmp = re.sub(r'[Dr.|Prof.]', '', text)
print(re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9]*', '', tmp))
```

Would that work?

it would print:

```
,      '    -   !!
```

The output is capturing the text in between the parentheses, in your question.

Comment: I don't want to throw away any words as the primary use of this regular expression is to use re.split so I can tokenize the string according to the captured characters.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.